Not able to submit multiple signed transactions through off-chain worker
I have to submit 2 signed extrinsics through off-chain worker. The code structure of my off-chain worker is like this:
fn offchain_worker(block_number: BlockNumberFor<T>) {

            if !sp_io::offchain::is_validator() {
                return;
            }
            log::info!("Hello from ocw!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (block_number.saturated_into::<u32>() % 100 as u32) != 0 {
                return;
            }

            let signer = Signer::<T, T::IdentifierId>::any_account();
            if !signer.can_sign() {
                log::error!("No local accounts available");
                return;
            }

// First submission of signed transaction
            let _ = signer.send_signed_transaction(|_account| Call::set_validator {});

            // Some time taking logic, which also included hitting multiple HTTP Requests

// 2 Second submission of signed transaction. 

if let Some((_, res)) = signer.send_signed_transaction(|_account| {
                        Call::second_submission_call {
                            setting_id,
                        }
                    }) {
                        match res {
                            Ok(_) => {
                                // Extrinsic call succeeded
                                log::info!("Extrinsic call succeeded");
                            },
                            Err(e) => {
                                log::error!("Error ");
    }





}


First submission of signed transaction is done successfully. But It skips to call second_submission_call. However it gives me message Extrinsic call succeeded without submitting the call. This also does not give any error in log.
Please let me know if I am missing anything. I am starting my node in dev mode using  ./target/release/mychain --dev.
